# With R, how do i assign values to a new column based on numbers that fall within a range?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

i have a column called reported age that can range from 0 to 100.

```
Report age|
         5
        82
        17
        39
        67
```

I would like to create a script that assigns a new column called Age Group

```
Report age|Age Group|
         5    5 to 9
        82  80 to 84
        17  15 to 19
        39  35 to 39 
        67  64 to 69
```

I know if i have

```
df <-df %>%
    mutate(Age_Group = ifelse(`Report age` <5, "Under 5", No)
```

I will get two outcomes. I want to set up way more. Under 5, 5 to 9, 10 to 14, 15 to 19, and so on until "85 years and over".

Comment: Take a look at the `questionr` package. It allows to split data into groups interactivelly. https://juba.github.io/questionr/reference/icut.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cut` to create the group

```
library(dplyr)
brks <- c(5, 9, 15, 35, 39, 64, 69, 80, 84)

df %>%
   mutate(Age_Group = cut(`Report age`, 
      breaks = c(-Inf, brks, Inf),
      labels = c("under 5", paste(head(brks, -1),
                " to ", tail(brks, -1)), "85 years and over")))
```

Comment: And, perhaps, if the breaks are defined as `brks <- c(-Inf, 5, 9, 15, 19, 35, 39, 64, 69, 80, 84, Inf)` you could add `labels = paste(head(brks, -1), "to", tail(brks, -1))` as a parameter to the `cut`.

Comment: how would i add for the first label and last label since they would be different. Instead of 0 to 4 i have "under 5". instead of 84 to 100 i have "85 years and over".

Comment: @user35131 you can add a custom label with `c`

Comment: @user35131 i updated the post.  can you please check

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you.